How TBB and DCB work in branching the flow?
I am new to ARM Cortex and facing difficulty to understand how TBB branches.
Code snippet attached:
TBB [PC,R1]
BrTable1 
DCB ((P0 - BrTable1)/2) 
DCB ((P1 - BrTable1)/2)

Now, my understanding is as follows:
TBB [PC,R1] will try to look for BrTable1 at PC + 4 (next instruction). Instead of PC, I can also give BrTable1 pointer here. R1 is counter and for next N cycles depending on R1 possible values, it will have cases.
Branching will happen as : PC_new = (BrTable1_pointer) + 2 * (data written at BrTable1_pointer + R1)) whereas R1 will be as a up-counter from 0 to X (For 8 bit, X = 255)
For R1 = 0, DCB ((P0 - BrTable1)/2) will

Branch my code to (BrTable1 + 2 * ((P0 - BrTable1)/2))
Branch my code to (BrTable1 + (P0 - BrTable1))
Branch my code to P0

Now this is as per expectation also.
Query
Intention is to compare the value of R1 and accordingly branch.

Is my understanding correct?
If I want to write only 2 cases for R1 == 0 and R1 == 10 then should I write my DCB instruction at ( BrTable1 + 10 ) location or is there any method to write it in next instruction only?
Do I have any control on R1?



Apart from the “for next N cycles” bit, which I'm not sure what it means, this seems to be correct.  Though note that all of R1 is used, not just the low 8 bits.   TBB is particularly useful for dense branch tables.  If your table is sparse, it might be better to just use a conditional branch or two.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. Copy the code into a code block instead (see my edit of your code snippet for how to correctly format a code block).

@LalitArora Always happy to help, but please do [edit] your question and replace your picture with code.
